# Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

[image]I am trying to migrate from rx5 to rx6 by following the guide [here](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/blob/HEAD/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md). Initially, I installed along with the rxjs-compat package and everything works fine. However, when I try to remove the rxjs-compat package, I am getting an exception `Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'`. I used the rxjs-5-to-6-migrate to perform the migration

I am using this statement for Subscription : import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

For reference this is my branch- https://github.com/akshita31/omnisharp-vscode/tree/rxjs_update and this is the corresponding pull request that lists all the changes - https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/pull/2830

Comment: If you (or any of your dependencies) are using any import locations other than those mentioned in this comment, `rxjs-compat` will be required: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3896#issuecomment-455375670

Comment: @cartant As above I have added all my usages of rxjs and it seems to be conforming to the format you pointed out

Comment: Also, I executed the steps as listed https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3896#issuecomment-456416750, and use the tslint but I dont get any errors

Comment: "or any of your dependencies"

Comment: @cartant How do I check if any dependencies have it? Visit the code of each repo and check for rxjs. Any other way?

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the effected error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187676/discussion-between-akshita007-and-cartant).

Comment: What's the problem with `import { Subscription } from "rxjs";`? This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I updated all the dependencies to the latest versions and used the [rxjs-tslint-rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-tslint-rules) as follows

1. npm install rxjs-tslint-rules --save-dev
2. Then in my tslint.json add the rule `"rxjs-no-compat" : true`
3. Execute `./node_modules/.bin/tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json` in the project folder. This will give all the set of invalid imports
4. Resolve the invalid imports and then try removing the rxjs-compat package.
5. I also cleaned my npm cache - `npm cache clean --force`
6. If there are no more errors, we can as well remove the above tslint dependency from the package.json
   More details can be found in the issue.

Thanks @cartant for the help

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance still have some imports that are still using `rxjs-compat`?

With the migration from rxjs 5 to 6, you need to be very careful about all the imports, since you don't want to import some module from wrong the wrong path. I believe `rxjs-tslint` can help you.

Comment: `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p ./`
I used the above to perform the migration and when i run it now i dont get any errors/hints.

Comment: Also I am using tsc to convert my typescript sources to javascript

Comment: ```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "outDir": "out",
  "lib": [
   "es6"
  ],
  "inlineSourceMap": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "alwaysStrict": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, 
 },
 "exclude": [
  "syntaxes",
  ".vscode-test",
  "vsix"
 ]
}

Comment: This is my tsconfig.json